# Giving light style to text

Tags: android

I want my text view in android to be source sans pro light 36 PX. How can I set it to source sans and light format. Currently android offers only regular,bold and italics .

Comment: use custom typeface for it..

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find the .ttf file that is sans pro light, add it in the assets folder and apply it programaticlly.

[image]

And then you add it with this code:

```
tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontName);
```